# String .format() vs. % formatting with Unicode data

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8

With

```
print("    {:d}). {:s} ({:d})".format(i, account, num_char))
```

I get the error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

but when I change it to:

```
print "    %d). %s (%d)" % (i, account, num_char)
```

then there are no problem and output is identical with both prints.

So what is wrong in the first expression and why does it work in the second?

Comment: `.encode("utf-8")` but how is the output identical in both prints if one causes an error?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel My question was in title... but someone was change my title :) I ask why the first print was with error when second is ok

Comment: Yes, the question should not have been deleted in the edit, still I like the title because it is much more specific than "What is wrong with..." which is too generic. I edited and put the question where it belongs (in the question body). Hope it's okay.

Answer (score 8):

In the first example, you are calling the `format` method of `str` object passing `unicode` arguments. This causes an error. You should use

```
print(u"    {:d}). {:s} ({:d})".format(i, account, num_char))
```

instead.

In the second one, you are using the `%` operator which automatically returns `unicode` when either format or object is `unicode`. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations):

> 6. If the object or format provided is a unicode string, the resulting string will also be unicode.